# Nodes on arrows not aligned nicely

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, positioning, arrows, tikz-arrows

I've written the LaTeX for an automaton that looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the 'b' on the arrow from q1 to q3 is positioned lower than the 'a, b, c' on the arrow from q3 to q2.

Also, the 'b' on the edge from q2 to q3 is positioned lower than the 'a, c' on the arrow from q3 to q1.

I would like to have both node duos aligned nicely, that is, on the same baseline. However, it's not necessary that all four are on the same line.

It seems to me that my code should do this by itself, but somehow it doesn't work. Why?

Here's my code. I marked the two node duos with comments:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,arrows,calc,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,node distance=25mm]
\node[state,initial,accepting] (q0) {$q_0$};
\node[state,right=of q0] (q1) {$q_1$};
\node[state,right=of q1] (q2) {$q_2$};
\node[state,below=of $(q1)!0.5!(q2)$] (q3) {$q_3$};
\node[state,accepting,right=of q2] (q4) {$q_4$};

\draw (q0) edge[loop above] node[above] {a, b} (q0);
\draw (q0) -- node[above] {b, c} ++ (q1);
\draw (q1) edge[loop above] node[above] {a, c} (q1);
\draw (q1) edge[bend left] node[above] {a, b, c} (q2);
\draw (q2) -- node[below] {a, c} ++ (q1);
\draw (q2) edge[bend left] node[right] {b} (q3);             % ! duo B
\draw (q3) -- node[above left] {a, b, c} ++ (q2);            % ! duo A
\draw (q3) edge[bend left] node[left] {a, c} (q1);           % ! duo B
\draw (q1) -- node[above right] {b} ++ (q3);                 % ! duo A
\draw (q2) edge[loop above] node[above] {a, b, c} (q2);
\draw (q2) -- node[above] {c} ++ (q4);
\draw (q1) edge[out=60,in=120] node[above] {c} (q4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a `\strut` or define `text depth` for those nodes. I have also changed `above left`to `left` and `above right` to `right` appropriately.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,arrows,calc,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,node distance=25mm]
\node[state,initial,accepting] (q0) {$q_0$};
\node[state,right=of q0] (q1) {$q_1$};
\node[state,right=of q1] (q2) {$q_2$};
\node[state,below=of $(q1)!0.5!(q2)$] (q3) {$q_3$};
\node[state,accepting,right=of q2] (q4) {$q_4$};

\draw (q0) edge[loop above] node[above] {a, b} (q0);
\draw (q0) -- node[above] {b, c} ++ (q1);
\draw (q1) edge[loop above] node[above] {a, c} (q1);
\draw (q1) edge[bend left] node[above] {a, b, c} (q2);
\draw (q2) -- node[below] {a, c} ++ (q1);
\draw (q2) edge[bend left] node[right] {\strut b} (q3);             % ! duo B
\draw (q3) -- node[left] {\strut a, b, c} ++ (q2);            % ! duo A
\draw (q3) edge[bend left] node[left] {\strut a, c} (q1);           % ! duo B
\draw (q1) -- node[right] {\strut b} ++ (q3);                 % ! duo A
\draw (q2) edge[loop above] node[above] {a, b, c} (q2);
\draw (q2) -- node[above] {c} ++ (q4);
\draw (q1) edge[out=60,in=120] node[above] {c} (q4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You were first, but I provided the exotic solution ;)

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino Really exotic! ;)

Comment: the "c" on the arrows from "q2" to "q4" and from "q1" to "q4" are still lower than the rest, although the latter is unlikely to be noticed.

Comment: @barbarabeeton True as it does't have a `,`. Adding `\strut` or defining `text depth` should solve it.

Comment: @barbarabeeton that could indeed be solved the same way, I checked. Thank you once again, Harish Kumar. I'm using `text depth` rather than `\strut` so that I don't have to keep it in mind for the rest of the picture.

Answer (score 6):

As first thing, I would add the options `text height=1ex, text depth=0pt` in the `tikzpicture`s  option to force all labels having the same (vertical) size.

Having done this, the problems

> As you can see, the 'b' on the arrow from q1 to q3 is positioned lower than the 'a, b, c' on the arrow from q3 to q2.
>
> Also, the 'b' on the edge from q2 to q3 is positioned lower than the 'a, c' on the arrow from q3 to q1.

are magically fixed.

An alternative and exotic solution is to name the important node, say the one with `a,b,c` and define `b`'s place in terms of the location of the important node. That is:

```
\draw (q1) -- node[shift={(label-abc.west)}, xshift=-3.5mm] {b} ++ (q3);
```

The complete code:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,arrows,calc,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,node distance=25mm, text height=1ex, text depth=0pt]
\node[state,initial,accepting] (q0) {$q_0$};
\node[state,right=of q0] (q1) {$q_1$};
\node[state,right=of q1] (q2) {$q_2$};
\node[state,below=of $(q1)!0.5!(q2)$] (q3) {$q_3$};
\node[state,accepting,right=of q2] (q4) {$q_4$};

\draw (q0) edge[loop above] node[above] {a, b} (q0);
\draw (q0) -- node[above] {b, c} ++ (q1);
\draw (q1) edge[loop above] node[above] {a, c} (q1);
\draw (q1) edge[bend left] node[above] {a, b, c} (q2);
\draw (q2) -- node[below] {a, c} ++ (q1);
\draw (q2) edge[bend left] node[right] {b} (q3);             % ! duo B
\draw (q3) -- node[above left](label-abc) {a, b, c} ++ (q2); % ! duo A
\draw (q3) edge[bend left] node[left] {a, c} (q1);           % ! duo B
\draw (q1) -- node[shift={(label-abc.west)}, xshift=-3.5mm] {b} ++ (q3); % ! duo A
\draw (q2) edge[loop above] node[above] {a, b, c} (q2);
\draw (q2) -- node[above] {c} ++ (q4);
\draw (q1) edge[out=60,in=120] node[above] {c} (q4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: having set both `text height` and `text depth` is really helping in case of letters like *p*, *q*, *g* and so on.

For example:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,arrows,calc,positioning,fit}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,node distance=25mm, text height=1ex, text depth=0pt]
\node[state,initial,accepting] (q0) {$q_0$};
\node[state,right=of q0] (q1) {$q_1$};
\node[state,right=of q1] (q2) {$q_2$};
\node[state,below=of $(q1)!0.5!(q2)$] (q3) {$q_3$};
\node[state,accepting,right=of q2] (q4) {$q_4$};

\draw (q0) edge[loop above] node[above] {a, b} (q0);
\draw (q0) -- node[above] {b, c} ++ (q1);
\draw (q1) edge[loop above] node[above] {a, c} (q1);
\draw (q1) edge[bend left] node[above] {a, b, c} (q2);
\draw (q2) -- node[below] {a, c} ++ (q1);
\draw (q2) edge[bend left] node[right] (label-g) {g} (q3);             % ! duo B
\draw (q3) -- node[draw,above left](label-abc) {a, b, c} ++ (q2); % ! duo A
\draw (q3) edge[bend left] node[left] (label-ac) {a, c} (q1);           % ! duo B
\draw (q1) -- node[draw,above right] {q} ++ (q3);                 % ! duo A
\draw (q2) edge[loop above] node[above] {a, b, c} (q2);
\draw (q2) -- node[above] {c} ++ (q4);
\draw (q1) edge[out=60,in=120] node[above] {c} (q4);

\node[draw,fit=(label-g)(label-ac)]{};
\draw (label-ac.base)--(label-g.base);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: would `depth = 0pt` work if "p" or "q" were in the labels?  (the comma isn't deep enough to cause a problem, but descenders on letters might be.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Yes, definitely. Let me add some comment on this in the answer in a few minutes.

Answer (score 3):

mostly off-topic, for exercise how to make diagram code shorter :-). also some additional explanation is given and proposed to use `tikz` library `quotes.

as stated in other answers, you need to define spaces for comas in your edge labels. this can be done on two ways:

- as proposed [Claudio Fiandrino](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/13304/claudio-fiandrino): determine `text height=1ex` and set `text depth=0pt`. this is cause, that letters `b` and commas touch node's top and bottom border respectively
- as proposed @user11232: use of strut at each sloped edge label's node contents, which make those nodes equal height and depth

in mwe below i follow to [Claudio Fiandrino](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/13304/claudio-fiandrino) approach, however the node size is defined differently and, in my opinion, more correctly. for edge labels are used `edge quotes`:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, automata,
                calc,
                positioning,
                quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[-Straight Barb,
node distance = 25mm,
         auto = left,
every edge quotes/.style = {inner sep=1pt,     % that labels are closer to edges
                            text height=1.5ex, % equal height, 
                            text depth=2pt,    % space for commas
                                               % however this depth is not sufficient for letters as p,q, ...
                                               % for them is better 0.25ex or slightly more
                            font=\small}       % smaller letters, gives a nicer result
                        ]
\node (q0)  [state,initial,accepting]         {$q_0$};
\node (q1)  [state,right=of q0]               {$q_1$};
\node (q2)  [state,right=of q1]               {$q_2$};
\node (q3)  [state,below=of $(q1)!0.5!(q2)$]  {$q_3$};
\node (q4)  [state,accepting,right=of q2]     {$q_4$};
%
\draw   (q0) edge[loop above, "{a, b}"]     ()
        (q0) edge["{b, c}"]                 (q1)
        (q1) edge[loop above, "{a, c}"]     ()
        (q1) edge[bend left, "{a, b, c}"]   (q2)
        (q2) edge["{a, c}"]                 (q1)
        (q2) edge[loop above, "{a, b, c}"]  ()
        (q2) edge[bend left, "b"]           (q3)    % ! duo B
        (q2) edge["c"]                      (q4)
        (q3) edge["{a, b, c}"]              (q2)    % ! duo A
        (q3) edge[bend left, "{a, c}"]      (q1)    % ! duo B
        (q1) edge["b"]                      (q3)    % ! duo A
        (q1) edge[out=60,in=120, "c"]       (q4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]